# Searchkick not being found - undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby, sinatra, searchkick

I'm trying to use searchkick along with my Neo4j database and Sinatra. I'm getting this undefined local variable or method error:

`NameError: undefined local variable or method 'searchkick' for Movie:Class`

Here is my model:

```
class Movie
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  searchkick

  property :id
  property :movieID
  property :title
  property :year
  property :imdB
  property :rtRating
  property :poster
end
```

and my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'searchkick'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'neo4j'
gem 'haml'
gem 'shotgun'
```

I've restarted my Sinatra server, checked that Elasticsearch is running. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Have you required it before using `searchkick`?

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j is not a supported backend for searchkick as of version 1.3.6. searchkick works with ActiveRecord, Mongoid, and NoBrainer. The examples in the documentation show ActiveRecord:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchkick
end
```

If you were using a supported database then you would ensure that your model class inherits from the appropriate class to expose the searchkick methods in it.